# How to get the namespace of a map with uniformly namespaced keys?

Tags: clojure, namespaces, maps

Is there a way to get the namespace of a map with uniformly name spaced keys?

For example:

`(map-ns {:some/key :val :some/other :val ,,,})  => “some”)`

Answer (score 2):

```clj
(->> m keys (map namespace) set)
```

Above will give you set of all namespaces, or you can return nil if size > 1.

Answer (score 1):

If the map is not empty and all of its keys have the same namespace, the following suffices:

```clj
(def map-ns (comp namespace first keys))
```

Alternatively:

```clj
(def map-ns (comp namespace ffirst))
```

And here is a version that returns `nil` when the map is empty or has keys with different namespaces:

```clj
(def map-ns
  (comp
    #(if-not (next %) (first %))
    distinct
    (partial map namespace)
    keys))
```

Alternatively:

```clj
(def map-ns
  (comp
    #(if-not (next %) (first %))
    distinct
    (partial map (comp namespace key))))
```